# Remote Desktop Software with USB passthrough

Tags: remote-desktop, gaming

I want to set up a virtual Windows 10 with steam and all of my games and to be able to remote desktop in over the internet and use my usb game controllers.

Is there some remote desktop software with a Windows Server that will give me sound and raw usb passthrough. Ideally with linux and macOS client support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steam Link](https://store.steampowered.com/remoteplay) is designed for exactly this use-case. You log in on steam on both the remote and local machine and can play games running on the hardware of the remote instance and stream a Steam-compatible controller input and video output from the remote to your local machine. It is free of charge

Comment: Thanks for sharing – but could you please be a bit more detailed? Normally this post would be converted into a comment, as it lacks essential information. For example, how does it meet the requirements? What makes it especially recommendable? How much does it cost? For details, please see [our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185).